# Hide CCK field group based on taxonomy term in Drupal6?

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-6, cck, drupal-taxonomy

I have a generic content type ("property") that has a bunch of content sorted via taxonomy. How can I hide or display CCK fields (or better yet, groups of CCK fields) based on taxonomy term selected? Should I do this via jQuery? Views?

Alternately -- if I have the taxonomy term-specific CCK fields structured in collapsed fieldset groups, how can I uncollapse the fieldset when the relevant taxonomy term is selected? (I'm guessing this would be a good candidate for quick jQuery code)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You really need two modules:

1. Conditional Fields -- http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields
2. Content Taxonomy -- http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy

In short, you add a Content Taxonomy field to a content type, then you can use Conditional Fields to conditionally display things. Works really well, actually.